# How to import images into initialState array of objects, then map through it to be displayed?

Tags: reactjs

I am building an app that allows the user to enter some information about an album. It then displays that information in a card format.

I have some local images in an **assets** folder in my **src** directory.

How do I import the images into the objects...

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from 'react';
import appReducer from './AppReducer';

const initialState = {
  albums: [
    {
      id: 1,
      // cover: 'HOW DO I INSERT AN IMAGE HERE...',
      name: 'Purple Rain',
      artist: 'Prince',
      year: '1984',
      genre: 'Pop',
    },...
  ]
};

export const GlobalContext = createContext(initialState);
```

...then display them in the `initialState` album list?

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import { GlobalContext } from '../context/GlobalState';

export const AlbumList = () => {
  const { albums, removeAlbum } = useContext(GlobalContext);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {albums.length > 0 ? (
        <React.Fragment>
          {albums.map((album) => (
            <div class="bg-white shadow p-3 m-3 rounded lg:w-64">
              <div>
                <img src="...AND USE IT HERE TO BE DISPLAYED" alt="album cover"></img>
              </div>

              <div class="mt-6">
                <p class="text-lg text-bold tracking-wide text-gray-600 mb-2">
                  {album.name}
                </p>
```

The `name`,`artist`, and `year`are displayed, but I can not get the images to display.
I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582405/react-wont-load-local-images/34583854#34583854) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60270043/mapping-through-array-of-objects-to-display-images), among other solutions, but I can't figure it out.

I'm just learning, so if more context or info is needed please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need import images as components!
Create folder with assets images and import to GlobalContext:

```
import PurpleRain from './assets/purple_rain.jpg';
```

and add to initial state:

```
const initialState = {
  albums: [
    {
      id: 1,

      cover: PurpleRain

      name: 'Purple Rain',
      artist: 'Prince',
      year: '1984',
      genre: 'Pop',
    },...
  ]
};
```

and use:

```
...
<div>
  <img src={album.cover} alt="album cover"></img>
</div>
...
```

Comment: You know what, I had already tried this, but for some reason I was putting braces when adding it to initial state `{ PurpleRain }` Thank you!

Comment: What if we have 100 or more elements in the albums array, do we also import 100 or more assets ? Yes we can but don't you think it will add up more lines of import code.

Answer (score 1):

```
const initialState = {
  albums: [
    {
      id: 1,
      // add a key for your img src here,
      src: '....',
      name: 'Purple Rain',
      artist: 'Prince',
      year: '1984',
      genre: 'Pop',
    },

    /*
     * Rest of objects
     * .
     * .
     */
  ],
};

// Then use map like this:
{
  albums.map(album => (
    <div class='bg-white shadow p-3 m-3 rounded lg:w-64'>
      <div>
        {/* Pull out src from current iteration (`album`) */}
        <img src={album.src} alt='album cover'></img>
      </div>

      <div class='mt-6'>
        <p class='text-lg text-bold tracking-wide text-gray-600 mb-2'>
          {album.name}
        </p>{' '}
      </div>
    </div>
  ));
}
```